# Java/Scala code sample for querying Hive/HBase tables using SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am able to work  SparkSQL queries  on hive and hbase tables using shell commands.Now I am looking for java/scala code for direct tables of hive and hbase. Anybody is working on this please share me the code samples. I tried in google but its not working for me.

I am updating question with my code and output as follows,

code:

```
object HbaseScalaSample {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("local[*]").setSparkHome("spark://master01:7077");

      val context = new SparkContext(conf)
      //val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(context)
      println("before hive context =====  " + context)
      println(context.sparkUser)
      val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(context)

      println("hive context =====  " + sqlContext)

      import sqlContext.implicits._

      println("before query context =====  " )

    //  val result = sqlContext.sql("select * from test_sample.police_station_juridiction limit 1")
val result = sqlContext.sql("show databases")

      println("after query context =====  " )

      result.show()



     }

}
```

output:

```
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_all_databases
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO audit: ugi=tmpl1684  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_all_databases   
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_functions: db=default pat=*
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO audit: ugi=tmpl1684  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_functions: db=default pat=* 
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog(HiveSharedState.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog(HiveSessionState.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer(HiveSessionState.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:582)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:682)
    at HbaseScalaSample$.main(HbaseScalaSample.scala:36)
    at HbaseScalaSample.main(HbaseScalaSample.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:189)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
    ... 23 more
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.127:4040
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/10/16 18:20:06 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\tmpl1684\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-6701cfb8-e178-4711-84d4-89d57da4dbfa
```

in spark-shell cmd prompt:

```
spark-shell
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
.
scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from test_sample.police_station_juridiction limit 1").collect()
```

result:

```
res0: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1.0,Hennur Police Station,null,null,null,POLYGON ((77.65560130784614 13.019060286311245, 77.656408100047088 13.020235045175891, 77.657542928637426 13.021478901432321, 77.658216733112923 13.023241020438837, 77.659812585818088 13.025210432730312, 77.66144390191667 13.027318032046464, 77.663811083429337 13.028803706031669, 77.664156851515443 13.029002371063319, 77.664405095269558 13.031109938105049, 77.66405046133508 13.031317238812122, 77.6647951925975 13.033148387518626, 77.665043436351638 13.035186820144828, 77.665220753318863 13.038209888463735, 77.668199678368481 13.037726200014607, 77.670611189122937 13.037380707686342, 77.671107676631209 13.038762674104895, 77.672845382910154 13.038659026891253, 77.672987236483962 13.03879722316646, 77....
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Get HiveContext from your SparkContext:

```
val hiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html

**Step 2.** Run any SQL query you like:

```
hiveContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (id INT)")
```

Comment: i tried with the same but it's giving NullPointerException for hiveContext variable.

Comment: You should update your question with both your code and output.

Comment: I updated my question please go through that and suggest me , how to use queries on tables.